# Where can I download Orthomosaic images in geotiff format for Agricultural Use case

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection

Please I want to know where I can get an open source Drone aerial View images in geotiff format for research purposes.

Image that displays crop row, weeds, livestock etc.

Besides OpenAerialMap is there any other website where i can get such images. Please suggest to me.The images should be in Geotiff format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to get those data. I have been working on cattle health monitoring with machine learning and we create our own dataset by setting up cameras on the farm. Most of these data are not shareable. Andrew William et al have created multiple publicly available datasets. Check out [AerialCattle2017](https://data.bris.ac.uk/data/dataset/3owflku95bxsx24643cybxu3qh) , they are collected from done but cropped for individual cattle. The best option for you to find journal papers that deal with similar datasets and ask the corresponding author regarding access.